# Producing E and B mode maps using CAMB and Healpy

Tags: healpy

I have been trying to make E and B mode maps using CAMB and healpy, however what I have produced so far doesn't really look like much.

I am using CAMB to produce simulated maps at the following link:
http://lambda.gsfc.nasa.gov/toolbox/tb_camb_form.cfm,
and I am keeping all the default parameters other than checking the box for tensor cl's and varying r.

with this I have been using the following code to produce maps:

```
# read in the power spectra produced by camb, ordering is: [TT, EE, BB, TE]
cl = hp.read_cl('scalar_and_tensor_power_spectra_produced_by_CAMB.fits')

# set the random seed for phase information
numpy.random.seed(some number) #Im using 1 for now

#Produce E mode and B mode maps
EEmap = hp.synfast(cl[1], NSIDE) 
BBmap = hp.synfast(cl[2], NSIDE)
```

A quick google search shows very different looking results from what Im getting, which you can see at the following links:
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ifvrpt&s=9#.VmY7Jx8So8o
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=a5ngx&s=9#.VmY7KR8So8o

I was expecting to see certain patterns in E and B due to the their being gradient and curl components, which are evident in images I found online, but not in my products.

So I have three questions:

1. Is there an error in the logic I am using to produce the maps?
2. Is extra filtering required in order to see the expected E and B patterns?

   - something like at the following link:
     http://cosmologist.info/polar/EBsupport.html
3. In versions of healpix other than healpy there is an argument in mollview called POLARIZATION (http://healpix.jpl.nasa.gov/html/idlnode33.htm#idl:mollview:polarization)
   in which setting POLARIZATION = 3 allows you to overplot the polarization information as headless vectors. This is what I think they are doing here:
   http://bicepkeck.org/media/b_over_b_rect_BICEP2.png
   & the first image here:
   https://inspirehep.net/record/787860/plots,
   Is there a way to do this in healpy? As the POLARIZATION argument does not seem to be included in this version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. see the help of `synalm` http://healpy.readthedocs.org/en/1.x/generated/healpy.sphtfunc.synalm.html#healpy.sphtfunc.synalm, if you do `hp.synfast(cl)` that is creating a temperature map with those `cl` in temperature.
   You should create a list of Cl for each component, i.e. TT, EE, BB, TE and then have all Cl to zero and just one nonzero.
2. you could smooth the output map with a gaussian beam of let's say 1 degree in order to simulate how a real instrument would look at that signal.
3. No support for plotting vectos in `healpy`

Comment: I think maybe this is stemming from and insufficient knowledge of how E and B modes work. If synfast(cl) produces IQU maps in which there is only a contribution from B (because everything else was set to zero), then is it right to say B = sqrt(Q^2 + U^2)? or something like that?

Comment: no, B is in another base, it is when you take the harmonic transform, it is alrways used in power spectrum domain. sqrt(Q^2 + U^2) is P, that is total polarization amplitude.

Comment: When I do what I think you are saying: synfast([zeros, zeros, BB cl's, zeros]), I get out an IQU map (I think) with a zero intensity component and nonzero Q and U components. How should I interpret this? Is this method not a method for producing E and B maps? Or maybe I am just confused about what E and B 'maps' are?

Comment: correct, you get an IQU map, that polarization signal in Q and U is the source of your B modes. E and B are in angular power spectrum domain, Q and U in map. check http://background.uchicago.edu/~whu/polar/webversion/polar.html or one of the books about cosmology (Liddle or Partridge or Durer)

Comment: I think it all makes sense to me now (relatively). Thank you for the help.